# Same address and not the same values with const

Tags: c, pointers, casting, memory-address

I found a little strange thing in a simple C code.
Actually, I have 2 variables, the first is a `const` variable and the second is a pointer on this first variable.

The thing is that if I print the 2 addresses, they are the same but if I print the values they are differents:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int                         main(void)
{
    bool const              b = true;
    bool                    *adr_b = (bool*)&b;

    *adr_b = false;
    printf("%p\n%p\n", &b, adr_b);
    printf("str = %d %d\n", b, *adr_b);

    printf("%p\n%p\n", &b, adr_b);
    return (0);
}
```

How is it possible ?

**EDIT**

In fact, I know that this behavior is undefined but this is a *technical* question : **HOW** an address can store 2 differents values ?

Comment: So you intentionally invoke _undefined behaviour_ and wonder why your code behaves undefined? Leran what casts are for and **never ever** use a cast if you don't fully understand what it does! You actively work against your compiler by telling it not to complain.

Comment: And don't get fancy with formatting! The code is hard to read.

Comment: "**HOW** an address can store 2 differents values ?"-- you are mistaken in thinking that an address is storing 2 values here. This program has undefined behavior (more than once), and as such is completely invalid. Further, when I compile and run this on my system (ignoring warnings) I get `str = 0 0` as output. Undefined behavior is meaningless.

Comment: The compiler may decide it knows that `b` can't change (it is `const`), so it doesn't need to look at the stored value again — it knows what it must be.  It may decide it doesn't know with `adr_b` and look at memory.  But that's only a possibility.  Any result is valid since the code has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour. You're modifying a `const` variable.

[C11 Standard Appendix J.2. Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> An attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type ([6.7.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3)).

The Appendix J.2, though non-normative, is handy for finding the actual normative location within the standard. [6.7.3 in paragraph 6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6) says:

> 6 If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.133)

---

Since you attempted - and successfully modified - an object defined with a const-qualified type (`const bool b`) through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type `bool` (here `*adr_b`), the C standard "imposes no requirements" for the behaviour of the program thereafter. There be [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demon).

Comment: As a side-note: Appendix J is informal only. It is not autoritative. (It summarises information found in other chapters, though, which _are_ autoritative. I don't mean it is wrong)

Comment: @Olaf ok ok... quoted 6.7.3.

Comment: I was fine with the answer, except that I think the question exactly gets what it asks for. One does not add a cast without reason, so I assume OP first got a warning ("assignment removes `const` qualifier" or similar), then added the cast "because that way the compiler does not complain, thus the cast fixed it" (I got that "excuse" from a so-called professional programmer once!)